# Edit text field to recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to send the `editText` field to `recycler list` in next `activity` but I can't obtain it. The problem is I can't see the list of `editText` field I have added in the list. For example: when i add mercury from `editText` and click save `button` I can see mercury in the `recyclerView`. But again when I write venus and click save button mercury disappears and venus appears.

This is my recycler `adapter`.

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> nameList){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    itemsName = nameList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view,parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsName ? itemsName.size() : 0);

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    onItemClickListener = listener;
}

public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener(){
    return onItemClickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
}

public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private RecyclerViewAdapter parent;
    TextView textItemName;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewAdapter parent) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.herecomes);
    }

    public void setItemName(CharSequence name){
        textItemName.setText(name);
    }

    public CharSequence getItemName(){
        return textItemName.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
        }
    }
}}
```

This is the `activity` having `editText` field from where I send the field value after clicking save `button`.

```
 public class MyEditor extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText textIn,txtHeading;
Button buttonAdd,btnsave;

ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editor);
    txtHeading = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heading);
        buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

    btnsave =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     String newName = txtHeading.getText().toString().trim();
            if(newName.length()!=0) {
                nameList.add(newName);
                txtHeading.setText("");


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuilderPage.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", nameList);
                nameList.add(newName);
                int listsize = nameList.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
                    Log.i("Lists are", nameList.get(i));
                    Log.i("Lists are", "The size of array is:" + nameList.size());
                }


                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(MyEditor
                        .this, "You added" + newName.toUpperCase() + "in your view", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
 }}
```

This is the class that contains `recyclerView`

```
  public class BuilderPage extends ActionBarActivity implements    
     RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.builder_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<String> nameList = 
      getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
        myRecyclerView = 
     (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_builderxml);

        linearLayoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(this,

                        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);


        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,nameList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

slidingDrawer.open();


    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed() {
            slideHandleButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrowup));


        }
    });
    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened() {
            slideHandleButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrowdown));



        }
    });
}

@OnClick(R.id.imgviewtextbox)
public void OnClick_TextBox(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra("item","textbox");
    startActivity(intent);
}

@OnClick(R.id.imgviewplaintext)
public void OnClick_PlainText(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra("item","plaintext");
    startActivity(intent);
}


@OnClick(R.id.imgviewcheckbox)
public void OnClick_CheckBox(View view)
{
    dbHelper.Insert_RadioButton("CheckBox");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra("item","checkbox");
    startActivity(intent);
}

@OnClick(R.id.imgviewradiobutton)
public void OnClick_RadioButton(View view)

{
    dbHelper.Insert_RadioButton("RadioButton");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra("item","radiobutton");
    startActivity(intent);



}
```

Comment: when you back from activity contain recyclerView, the  `nameList ` still have same data or not?

Comment: I am not using the back button i have drawer layout to move to MyEditor

Comment: no the text  fields items in the recycler disappears.

Comment: A button on drawer layout startActivity `MyEditor` and `Save` button startActivity `BuilderPage`? If so, When you open `MyEditor` again, `nameList ` is recreated. It will not save last data you saved. You need to save last value before start next Activity.

Comment: How can i achive this?

Comment: It has many ways to do, using `static`, `sharedpreferences`,...

Comment: what should i change in myEditor class?

Comment: It's up to you to decide the way you want to save your data. If it saves only when your app run and clear after quit => static. If you want to save and not clear event quit your app => sharedpreferences, database, SQLite... Google it. All of them are easy to use.